# Xstream with CDATA in server got IOException, but works in Eclipse

Tags: utf-8, xstream, cdata

I've searched and got the solution for adding CDATA tag for Axstream, and it worked well in Eclipse in my machine. However, after I deployed my code to tomcat server, it always failed with IOException at toXML(t, writer) or toXML(t), I've also tried to make the writer to "UTF-8", but still no luck.

My code for handle CDATA is:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream( new XppDriver(){
@Override
public HierarchicalStreamWriter createWriter(Writer out) {
  return new PrettyPrintWriter(out){
  boolean cdata = false;
  @Override
  public void startNode(String name) {
    super.startNode(name);
    cdata = name.equalsIgnoreCase("imagestream");
  }
  @Override
  protected void writeText(QuickWriter writer, String text) {
     if(cdata && !text.isEmpty()){
         writer.write("<![CDATA[");
         writer.write(text);
         writer.write("]]>");
     }else {
         writer.write(text);
  }
 }
};
}
}); 

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

xstream.toXML(t,writer);
xml = outputStream.toString("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace of the thrown IOException.

Comment: I didn't see stacktrace exception in system log, but the response I've got is IOException. I've debugged and tested it, It is only good after I've removed those override methods.

Comment: I've solved the problem by creating a new class MyPrettyPrintWriter, and override methods in the new class, and it works now.